# Youtube video is cut off at the bottom in swift application

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout

I am using [Swift-YouTube-Player](https://github.com/gilesvangruisen/Swift-YouTube-Player) for playing videos in my swift app. The layout is very simple it just has YouTubePlayerView, which I want to occupy the maximum space keeping aspect ratio.

[image: Layout]

But the video is cut off in the bottom in both horizontal and vertical orientations.

[image: Video in landscape]

How can I fix it?

**Update:**

The code for the controller is:

```
import UIKit
import YouTubePlayer

class PlayVideoController: UIViewController {

    var  videoId : String!

    @IBOutlet weak var youtubePlayer: YouTubePlayerView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        youtubePlayer.loadVideoID(videoId)
        youtubePlayer.sizeToFit()
     }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
     }
}
```

**Update:** 
My code should work and the answer from @ivarun also works.
The problem was that I edited YTPlayer.html putting there

```
    body { margin: 0; width:100%%; height:100%%; }
    html { width:100%%; height:100%%; }
```

When I reverted it to

```
* { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
html, body { width: 100%; height: 100%; }
```

It started to work again.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: Can you please provide sample code to us?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove Accept Ratio constraint and give Leading, Trailing, Top and Bottom 0 constant. It will work for you.

**Updated**

[image]

Comment: Does not help, still the same problem.

Comment: @KatyaGorshkova Check screenshot. it is working for me.